# A problem in Werner Greub's, Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem states the following: 
Let E be a vector space over a field $\Gamma$ of characteristic 0. Let $j:E \to E$ be a linear transformation such that $j^2=-id_{E}$. Then show that the dimension of E is even.

I can show this for a vector space over the reals or the rationals. However my proof fails for arbitrary fields of characteristic zero. Is the statement still true for arbitrary fields of characteristic zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\Gamma = \mathbb{C}$ and $E = \mathbb{C}$ the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $E \to E$, $x \mapsto ix$ a counterexample.

More generally:
The claimed statement holds for any field $\Gamma$ (of arbitrary characteristic) if and only if $-1$ does not have not square root in $\Gamma$:

If such a square root $\omega \in \Gamma$ exists, the one can take $E = \Gamma$ and the $\Gamma$-linear map $E \to E$, $x \mapsto \omega x$ as an counterexample.

If no such square root exists then let $j \colon E \to E$ be a linear transformation with $j^2 = -\operatorname{id}_E$ for some finite-dimensional vector space $E$.
Then
$$
    \det(j)^2
  = \det(j^2)
  = \det(-\operatorname{id}_E)
  = (-1)^{\dim E} \det(\operatorname{id}_E)
  = (-1)^{\dim E},
$$
which shows that $\det(j)$ is a square root of $(-1)^{\dim E}$.
By assumption $-1$ has no square root, so it follows that $(-1)^{\dim E} = 1$.
Note that $\operatorname{char} \Gamma \neq 2$ since otherwise $-1 = 1$ would have a square root.
Hence it follows from $(-1)^{\dim E} = 1$ that $\dim E$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

It is false over fields $F$ of characteristic $2$. Just take $\operatorname{Id}\colon F^n\longrightarrow F^n$, for any natural $n$.

Comment: It is also false for other finite characteristics.   For instance, with $F = \Bbb Z_{5}$, we have $j:x \mapsto 2x$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If you post your comment as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: I appreciate it but I am content just leaving the comment

Comment: I appreciate the counterexamples provided for finite characteristic. However, I am interested in the case where the field is arbitrary of characteristic 0.

Comment: @cdust314 But the question was “Is the statement still true for arbitrary fields?”

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The statement of the problem is about fields of characteristic zero, as I have written. However, I see the misunderstanding. I will edit the last part.

Comment: @cdust314 *Now* I find your question interesting, and hence I upvoted it.